# How to disable capture of std-out in JBoss?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

Using JBoss EAP 6.4 (AS 7.x I guess).

By default, JBoss' logging service is capturing all application output to stdout (and presumably stderr) and wrapping it in its own log4j-based logs. When running locally I want to totally disable this (annoying) feature<sup>1</sup>, but the references I've found on the Interwebs all either don't work or are for older versions of JBoss. I've tried excluding every possible logging framework in the `jboss-deployment-structure` configuration, passing `-Dorg.jboss.logging.per-deployment=false` as a system property, but still JBoss captures stdout.

How can I disable it in this version of JBoss?

---

[1] If you must know the reason, it's because we have detailed logging configuration via logback and when running locally in an IDE want to be able to see and control that log output in the console without JBoss' logging service getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard-coded in the entry points to capture `stdout` and `stderr`. This is done so both streams are written to the defined log handlers. Because of this there is no real clean way around it. However there are ways to make it at least look a little better.

You can create a new `console-handler` and define a `stdout` logger to ensure only the simple message is written though.

Here are some CLI commands to configure a logger named `stdout` to just print the message it receives.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=plain-formatter:add(pattern="%s")
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=plain-console:add(autoflush=true, target=System.out, named-formatter=plain-formatter)
/subsystem=logging/logger=stdout:add(use-parent-handlers=false, handlers=[plain-console])
```

*Note: It could be my test logback.xml configuration, but I had to use a pattern of `%s%n` for the `plain-formatter`.*

The only other option I can think of would be to write your own logback `ConsoleAppender` that creates an output stream based on `java.io.FileOutputStream.out` rather than using `System.out`.

Comment: I'll edit the question with this, but... even making it prettier isn't far enough. The problem is that our slf4j log calls specify a level (debug, info, error, etc) but JBoss logging wraps everything and outputs at the INFO level. So If I want to set my root logback level to WARN, for example, I see no application output on the console. I don't really understand why my WAR's logback.xml is affecting JBoss' stdout filtering, but that's what I've observed.

Comment: By the way, where does that configuration in the answer go?

Comment: Well the logback.xml would only be used if you include logback in your deployment. Are you wanting to configure your own log manager or are you wanting the container to take care of the logging configuration?

Comment: Oops sorry about that. I clarified the answer to indicate those are CLI commands.

Comment: Yes, both slf4j and logback are included in the WAR. What I want is to just turn off or bypass any logging services that JBoss has. Honestly, it just gets in my way and I prefer application-managed config via logback.

Comment: By excluding the logging subsystem in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, including slf4j and logback should do that. The one issue is the `ConsoleAppender` because `System.out` and `System.err` are captured by the main entry points. The only options around that are what I described above.